# How to retrieve value of type string in NSObject which is retrieved from web in JSON?

Tags: objective-c, json

I have an NSObject boastObj and it contains purchase property of type string. I am retrieving the value through `JSON parse` which is sub object to result.

```
@interface BoasterElite : NSObject    
{
    NSString* purchase;
}
```

**Following is the JSON.**

```
"results": [
    {
        "name": "UserName",
        "points": "2",
        "profile_photo": "https:\/\/scontent.fblr1-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/hphotos-xtf1\/v\/t1.0-9\/12004045_134589590222520_1895675040105383396_n.jpg?oh=17c11a393c141443bdd3bc1451a560a8",
        "purchase": [
            {
                "purchase_id": "1",
                "purchase_type": "car",
                "timeDate": "2016-04-01 00:10:49",
                "brand": "Ferrari",
                "model": "v3",
                "year": "2016",
                "photo": "https:\/\/cdn1.vox-cdn.com\/thumbor\/-pG8Dcb_qtRf6te3ug12FHhqUDs=\/1020x0\/cdn0.vox-cdn.com\/uploads\/chorus_asset\/file\/4156848\/Ferrari_F12tdf_3low.0.jpg",
                "message": "ferrari car in boaster app",
                "verify_id": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

Comment: NSString *name = [[json valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"name"];

Comment: I want to retrive purchase object

Comment: @interface BoasterElite : NSObject

{
NSString* purchase;
}

Answer (score 0):

Store the json values in NSDictionary or NSArray.

If you want retrieve NSString values means use

```
NSString *name = [[json objectForKey:@"results"] objectForKey:@"name"];



NSString *purchase_type = [[[json objectForKey:@"results"] objectForKey:@"purchase"] objectForKey:@"purchase_type"];
```

It may help you.

Comment: Don't use `valueForKey` unless you really need the KVC method. Use `objectForKey` or key subscripting

Comment: ok m able to access name n all but "purchase" type has sub attributes how should i access it

Comment: NSDictionary *purchase_type = [[json objectForKey:@"results"] objectForKey:@"purchase"] ;
After you can use  purchase_type dictionary to retrieve the values.

Comment: ok in "purchase" as a string type i got all attributes but in another view controller in table view i m accessing it as 
NSLog(@"Name:%@",boast_Obj.userName);
    NSLog(@"Points:%@",boast_Obj.boastPoints);

Comment: i want to access same for sub attributes of purchase object how can i do

Answer (score 0):

`results` is an array of dictionaries, assuming `json` is the JSON object

```
NSArray *results = json["results"];
```

You can get the `points` value with

```
NSString *points = results[0]["points"];
```

`purchase` is in the first item of the array and it's also an array of dictionaries.

```
NSArray *purchases = results[0]["purchase"];
NSDictionary *purchase = purchases[0];
```

Now you can get the values by keys for example

```
NSString *brand = purchase["brand"];
```

Comment: ya this is good what i am doing is m accessing it in another class by object of type  BoasterElite like NSLog(@"Name:%@",boast_Obj.userName); where BoasterElite is having properties of type string

Comment: - (id)initAllBoastsWithWJsonResultDict:(NSDictionary *)jsonResultDict{
    
    return [self initWithUserName:[jsonResultDict objectForKey:@"name"]
                           points:[jsonResultDict objectForKey:@"points"]
                        userPhoto:[jsonResultDict objectForKey:@"profile_photo"]
                         purchase:[jsonResultDict objectForKey:@"purchase"]];
    
    
}

Comment: You probably need to create somewhere an `BoasterElite` object and populate the properties with the values from JSON. Consider that `purchase` is an array of dictionaries rather than `NSString`

Comment: ya i m getting values in object how to retrive individual values like
cell1.userName.text=boast_Obj.userName;
    cell1.points.text=boast_Obj.boastPoints;
    cell1.userPhoto_retrieve=boast_Obj.userPhoto; these values m getting

Comment: I updated the answer how to get the `points` value. Once again: The value for `purchase` is **not** a string.

Comment: should i have to take purchase as NSDictionary type rather than string...??

Comment: Please read my answer and comments: The value for `purchase` is an array of dictionaries. In this particular case there is only one dictionary in the array at index 0.

Comment: all values m accessing only purchase i want to access like it is having  "purchase_id": "1",
                "purchase_type": "car",
                "timeDate": "2016-04-01 00:10:49",
                "brand": "Ferrari",
                "model": "v3",
                "year": "2016",
                "photo": "https:\/\/cdn1.vox-cdn.com\/thumbor\/-pG8Dcb_qtRf6te3ug12FHhqUDs=\/1020x0\/cdn0.vox-cdn.com\/uploads\/chorus_asset\/file\/4156848\/Ferrari_F12tdf_3low.0.jpg",
                "message": "ferrari car in boaster app",
                "verify_id": "0"

Comment: Sorry, **read my answer**, I described how to retrieve single values for keys from the `purchase` value (the `brand` line)